# automatically generate layouts based on field values in arcgis pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, fields-attributes, layouts, map-series

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.5.1.

I am creating maps of bird species distributions for 127 species, all over the same geographic area. I have a point feature class where each point is a bird sighting, with different symbols to represent breeding status.

I would like to create a layout for each species, using the same symbology and spatial extent for each layout. Effectively, I want to generate an identical layout for each unique value in the 'species' field of my point feature class. I thought this should be fairly straightforward to automate, but haven't been able to figure out how to do it. My first thought was creating a Map Series, but it seems my only option is to define the different maps in the series by spatial extent, rather than field values.

Is there a way to create a series of layouts defined by field values? I haven't much experience with Python so hoping that's not the only way to do this, but happy to learn if it is.